# Will Android Arch Comps be supported

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-architecture-components

This ([Will Xamarin support the new Android Architecture Components?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100021/will-xamarin-support-the-new-android-architecture-components)) is the only info I found regarding Android Arch Comps for Xamarin Android so far.

There are [3 NuGet `Xamarin.Android.Arch` packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xamarin.android.arch&prerel=false) released (last update 4 months ago), which only cover [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html).

> [Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common/1.0.0)
>
> [Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common 1.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common/1.0.1)
>
> [Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime/1.0.0)

What about [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html), [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of these components have respective .NET libraries that fit the purpose(RX-UI, Realm, MVVM Libraries, etc). With that said, they aren't bound yet because there isn't quite the demand for these items. You can however bind these yourself or even contribute to the open source project!

> We decided to only bind the small subset of Architecture Component libraries that are required dependencies by other support libraries for now. We haven't seen a lot of demand for the Architecture Components as there are a number of alternative and more cross platform ways to do data binding in .NET. Not against adding them by any means, they just haven't been a priority yet.

**Source:** https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/76#issuecomment-346521937

With that said, please add a ["+1" / "thumbs-up" reaction](https://github.com/blog/2119-add-reactions-to-pull-requests-issues-and-comments) to the original issue so maintainers know there is demand for the library:

https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/76

Comment: Is there any chance they eventually are binded ? We'd rather use native frameworks. Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the demand. An upvote would help indicate that.

Comment: Done. Last, I am trying to observe an `ILIfeOwner`, but I can't use `OnLifecycleEvent` annotation. Has this been implemented ? ( I have seen it [here](https://github.com/atsushieno/xamarin-android-architecture-components-binding/blob/master/Binding/ArchitectureComponentsSample/MainActivity.cs) ) Thanks.